# Trying to add child record fields into a single field in Parent object using trigger but getting an error?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have two objects. Child Object: Service_Item__c and Parent Object: Case, with master detail relationship. so when a record is inserted or updated I want to add Service_Id__c and Service_Description__c to the Parent custom field Service_Items__c with comma separated(field1__c,Field2__c).

I have copied and adjusted the code from [how to add child record fields into a single field in Parent object using trigger?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169641/how-to-add-child-record-fields-into-a-single-field-in-parent-object-using-trigge)

**However I am getting the following error message:**

Error   Error: Compile Error:

Service ID, Service Description from Service_Item__r) from Case where

^

ERROR at Row:1:Column:74

Didn't understand relationship 'Service_Item__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. at line 12 column 24

**Any help would be greatly appreciated :)**

**Trigger**

```
trigger updateVals on Service_Item__c(after Insert, after Update) {

List < Case > poList = new List < Case > ();
Set < Id > Po_Ids = new Set < Id > ();

for (Service_Item__c childObj: Trigger.new) {
    Po_Ids.add(childObj.Case__c);
}


if (Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate) {
    List < Case > po = [Select Id, Service_List__c, (Select Service ID, 
Service Description from Service_Item__r) from Case where Id IN: Po_Ids];
    for (Case p: po) {
        String concatenateString = '';
        for (Service_Item__c c: p.Service_Item__r) {
            concatenateString += c.Service_ID__c + ',' + c.Service_Description__c + ' : ';

        }
        p.Service_Items__c = concatenateString;
        poList.add(p);
    }


    update poList;

}

}
```

Comment: From refers to an object table and Service_Item__r is considered as a field. Other than that I don't understand why the SELECT is not crushing on "SELECT Service ID" as they should be separated by a comma or linked by an underscore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the plural of the related object. From `Service_Item__r` to this `Service_Items__r`. I assume that the plural for Service Item is `Service_Items__c` :)

It looks like not quite right:

```
if (Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate) {
    List < Case > po = [Select Id, Service_List__c, (Select Service ID, 
Service Description from Service_Item__r) from Case where Id IN: Po_Ids];
```

This part: `Service Description` what are those?

Comment: the Service Description and Service ID are two custom fields within the child object that I would like to add to concatenate. I have updated these to the API names and it has worked! Thanks for your help!